# Groovy remove part of string within < >

Tags: string, groovy

Hi In Groovy I need to remove part of string
the string.

```
 <Results xsi:type="xsd:string" 

        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Updated User 

            id:nish.test11</Results>
```

should look like " Updated User id:nish.test11

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the content looks like an XML,

```
def xml = """
 <Results xsi:type="xsd:string" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Updated User 
    id:nish.test11</Results>  
"""
```

it's better to use XmlSlurper than parsing/extracting strings by hand

```
def result = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)            

println result.toString()
```

this gives the desired result (the content of the `Result`)

Comment: You are welcome. If it works for you, could you please accept the answer so it doesn't appear as unanswered questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I run the code:

```
""" <Results xsi:type="xsd:string" 

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Updated User 

        id:nish.test11</Results>""".replaceAll( /<\/?[^<>]>/, '' ).replaceAll( /[\n\s]+/, ' ' )
```

it gives me

```
Updated User id:nish.test11
```

as output